# r: append mean of a subset of columns by name

Tags: r, append, mean

I have this df:

```
          webvisits1   webvisits2  webvisits3 webvisits4
s001          2            0           11           2
s002          11           2           23           3
s003          12           1            1           5
s004          13           5            5           0
s005          4            3            9           3
```

I need to create an output dataframe with an added columns containing the difference between the mean of webvisits(3-4) and webvisits (1-2), like so:

```
          webvisits1   webvisits2  webvisits3 webvisits4 difference_mean
s001          2            0           11           2        -5.5
s002          11           2           23           3        -6.5
s003          12           1            1           5         3.5
s004          13           5            5           0         6.5
s005          4            3            9           3        -2.5
```

Is there an easy way to do so, considering that column names (webvisits) are important?
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We subset the dataset into two (`df[1:2]`, `df[3:4]`), get the difference and then with `rowMeans` we find the `mean`, create a new column 'differenceMean' using `transform`.

```
df <- transform(df, differenceMean = rowMeans(df[1:2]- df[3:4]))
df 
#     webvisits1 webvisits2 webvisits3 webvisits4 differenceMean
#s001          2          0         11          2           -5.5
#s002         11          2         23          3           -6.5
#s003         12          1          1          5            3.5
#s004         13          5          5          0            6.5
#s005          4          3          9          3           -2.5
```

Answer (score 1):

rowSums function can sum rows of each variables, then after find difference between existing variables and take mean of them

```
library(dplyr)
 dt %>%
  mutate(difference_mean = (rowSums(dt[,2:3])-rowSums(dt[,4:5]))/2)

s.no webvisits1 webvisits2 webvisits3 webvisits4 difference_mean
1 s001          2          0         11          2            -5.5
2 s002         11          2         23          3            -6.5
3 s003         12          1          1          5             3.5
4 s004         13          5          5          0             6.5
5 s005          4          3          9          3            -2.5
```